# How to format html arrays

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays

I have a big form and I need to POST my HTML form in this array format. The problem I have is that how do I get stations numbered as 0, 1, 2, 3, ... as shown below?

```
$processes["stations"] = array(
        "0" => array(
            "name" => "Name 1",
            "id" => "2",
            "value"=>"15"
        ),
        "1" => array(
            "name" => "Name 2",
            "id" => "2",
            "value"=>"30"
        )
    );
```

This is my HTML form and can be generated dynamically by jQuery.

```
<input type="text" name="process[stations][name][]" />
<input type="text" name="process[stations][id][]" />
<input type="text" name="process[stations][value][]" />
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="text" name="process[stations][0][name]" />
<input type="text" name="process[stations][0][id]" />
<input type="text" name="process[stations][0][value]" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that didn't do it.

Comment: Based on your follow-up to @OmarJackman, yes, it did, you just need to extend it a bit using pretty basic JS.

Answer (score 0):

you would do it like this:

```
<input type="text" name="process[stations][0][name]" />
<input type="text" name="process[stations][0][id]" />
<input type="text" name="process[stations][0][value]" />


<input type="text" name="process[stations][1][name]" />
<input type="text" name="process[stations][1][id]" />
<input type="text" name="process[stations][1][value]" />
```

etc

Comment: The form is dynamic. How do I alter the number?

Comment: If you can alter the form dynamically, you can alter the number dynamically.

Comment: @ceejayoz The form is humongous and generated dynamically just by a click of a button `$(".machine-stations:first").clone().insertAfter(".machine-stations:last");` This is how I generate the form

Comment: @ceejayoz Stations are pulled from database, there total 16 stations therefore there are 16 of these `process[stations][1,2,3,...,16][name]`. I have a foreach loop I can have a counter and increment the number for each stations, that's no problem. But how can I alter the number if the form is duplicated? Thanks.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks, your answer is very enlightening!

Answer (score 0):

Use node.appendChild with a loop to dynamically generate the form with JavaScript / jQuery.

EDIT:
Try reading into [Adding elements to the DOM](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml)

Comment: Can you please be more specific?